# How to show Uk visa reference number in next subsequent application

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

In Dec 2010, my UK visa got refused due to insufficient bank statements provided. Subsequently I reapplied and this time provided the correct set of documents and got the visa. This travel was through my company and I am not sure how they provided the refusal details in the next application, ie whether it was given in the cover letter or in the application itself. Now I am planning to travel for tourism purposes and I am not sure if I need to include this reference number on the cover letter as well or not. I have already provided it in the application under the question - Have you been refused visa to the UK earlier?

Also I have colored print outs of my payslips in the company letterhead. Do I additionally need stamp and sign of the company as well on these payslips?